# Using a HTML hyperlink to call a JS function on the parent element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table as shown below. At the end of each non-header row, I have two links, one for copy and one for edit. When clicked, they should trigger a JavaScript function that is defined below.

```js
function editRow(el) {
    //alert function added for debug purposes
    alert(el.rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Tools</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20 October 2017</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:editRow(this)">Edit</a>
            <a href="javascript:copyRow(this)">Copy</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>19 October 2017</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:editRow(this)">Edit</a>
            <a href="javascript:copyRow(this)">Copy</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, the alert always says `undefined`. I think this is because the hyperlink is calling the function on the text and not the cell. How can I change the `editRow(this)` call to one that calls it on its parent element? I tried `editRow(parent)` and `editRow(this.parent)` but it didn't do anything useful.

Comment: If you `console.log(el)` in the function, you might learn what `this` actually is, and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when calling javascript using `javascript: editRow(this)`, the `this` is set to the `window` object

You can fix your code by installing the handlers from HTML, but you really should do it from JS.

Added an example below using the `onclick` HTML attribute for simplicity.

```js
function editRow(obj) {
   console.log('edit handler tagname', obj.tagName);
}

function copyRow(obj) {
   console.log('copy handler parent tr rowIndex', obj.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Tools</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20 October 2017</td>
    <td>
      <a onclick="editRow(this)" href="#">Edit</a>
      <a onclick="javascript:copyRow(this)" href="#">Copy</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19 October 2017</td>
    <td>
      <a onclick="editRow(this)" href="#">Edit</a>
      <a onclick="copyRow(this)" href="#">Copy</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Strangely that isn't working for me. I'll restyle the code and get back to you

Comment: @63penguin What do you mean, it's not working? What's not working? When I run it, I see the output: `edit handler tagname A` and 
`copy handler parent tr rowIndex 2` You should never just say: "it's not working". Instead, explain what happen/didn't happen and any error messages along with expected behavior

Comment: The error message: cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined

Comment: I mean in my own code, off StackOverflow. Your example works fine

Comment: Did you try it on my example above? You must have miscopied something

Comment: @63penguin I can't vouch for code you have never shown us; the question, as you have asked, has been answered ;)

Comment: Fixed, missing bracket had killed it :)